# How to pass an array to an user defined object or convert non-OO code to OO? javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop, object, encapsulation

I really have trouble with OO coding in js. I have written a piece of code which rotates through 3 divs, and pauses on hover of any div. This code is just regular js using an array/json as the input. the code is a bit long so sorry about that. I just need some guidance on how I can convert this primitive code to a better form, as in OO and encap. When I tried myself I could not pass the slides array/json to my defined object. Is there a trick or guideline i can follow on how to rewrite this to a better form?

Edit - What is a good guideline to follow so I can rewrite this with objects instead of global variables and loose functions

```
var slideIndex = 0;
var prevIndex = 0;
var t;

function initPromo(){
sortSlides();
nextPromo();
addListeners();
}    

function addListeners(){
for(var i=0; i<slides.length; i++) 
    $(slides[i].el).hover(function(){ stopPromo(); }, function(){ resumePromo(); });
}
function resumePromo(){ startTimer(); }

function stopPromo(){ clearTimeout(t); }

function nextPromo(){
    if(slideIndex > 0 || prevIndex > 0) $(slides[prevIndex].el).css("display","none");
    $(slides[slideIndex].el).css("display","block");
    prevIndex = slideIndex;
    slideIndex = (slideIndex<slides.length-1) ? slideIndex+1 : 0;
    startTimer();
}

function startTimer(){ t = setTimeout("nextPromo()", 3000); }

function SortByWeight(a,b) { return b.weight - a.weight; }
function SortByWeightFr(a,b) { return b.frWeight - a.frWeight; }

function sortSlides(){
    ($("body.en").length > 0) ? slides.sort(SortByWeight) : slides.sort(SortByWeightFr);    
}

var slides = [
{
    el:'#ps1',
    weight:1,
    frWeight:3
},
{
    el:'#ps2',
    weight:0.5,
    frWeight:6
},
{
    el:'#ps3',
    weight:4,
    frWeight:9
}
];
window.onload = function () {
    initPromo();    
};
```

HTML

```
<body class="en">
<div id="homepageSlides">
    <div id="promoSlides">
        <div id="ps1">ps1</div><div id="ps2">ps2</div><div id="ps3">ps3</div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Edit: Early days in OO coding, not asked in the right way

Comment: It is hard to find out what is precisely being asked here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well your "plain javascript" code is already taking you part way there.  The first function you have defined identies the domain object: Promo.

`var Promo = function () { };`

You have actions on an instance of promo, init, start, stop, resume, etc.  These can be defined on the prototype of `Promo`.

```
Promo.prototype.init = function() {
  // ...
};
```

It could get a little annoying typing prototype each time, so we could bundle the prototype into a pointer that allows us a lot easier access...

```
var Promo = function () { };
(function(obj) {

    obj.init = function() {
        // ...
    };

})(Promo.prototype);
```

So we've got some structure but we need to now separate concerns.  Throughout your plain javascript you've got config type data strewn through the code.  It's generally a good idea to isolate these bits of data to a single entry point for your object.

```
obj.init = function(_el) {
     // where _el is the base element of this widget
};
```

I see you're also using jQuery which is good because it gives you a lot of power.  One convention I like to use is instead of passing a huge amount of config data into a given widget, I like to give my objects minimal config and let them inspect the HTML to determine additional configuration data.  This has the added advantage of if you wanted to add slides in the future or otherwise make changes to the slide content you need'nt worry about changing the JS.

Let's say we were to alter the slide HTML to look like...

```
<div id="promoSlides">
    <div data-type="slide" data-slide-id="1">ps1</div>
    <div data-type="slide" data-slide-id="2">ps2</div>
    <div data-type="slide" data-slide-id="3">ps3</div>
</div>
```

Using jQuery we could identify how many slides are present.

```
obj.init = function(_el) {
    this.baseElement = $(_el);
    this.slides = this.baseElement.find('*[data-type="slide"]');
};
```

Now we're passing in minimal config, we've separated out the identification of the slides to the HTML, and we've got a nice pattern for a self-sufficient object.  The rest would be to fill in the details (totally untested, but something like this)...

```
var Promo = function () { };
(function (obj) {

    obj.init = function(_el, _delay) {

        // Initialize markup
        this.baseElement = $(_el);
        this.slides = this.baseElement.find('*[data-type="slide"]');
        this.slideDelay = _delay;

        // Sort slides
        // (not sure what's going on here)

        // Bind events
        this.baseElement
            .on('mouseenter', this.stop.bind(this))
            .on('mouseleave', this.start.bind(this));
    };

    obj.start = function() {
        this.timer = setInterval(this.advance.bind(this), this.slideDelay);
    };

    obj.stop = function() {
        clearInterval(this.timer);
    };

    obj.advance = function() {
        // Slide the visible slide off screen
        // (note: the parent tag will need overflow:hidden)
        var visible = this.baseElement.find('*[data-type="slide"]:visible');
        visible.animate({ left: '-' + (visible.width()) + 'px' }, 1000);
        // Slide the next slide in
        var next = visible.next();
        next.css('left', this.baseElement.width() + 1).animate({ left: '0' }, 1000);
    };

})(Promo.prototype);
```

Note that I made use of `bind` which isn't supported yet in older versions of IE.

Comment: thanks for the help, I understand part of the stuff you wrote here. I guess the main thing i don't get about the OO style is what "this" refers to at times. I have not grasp the OO concept

Comment: Check out this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply

Comment: And this:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 1):

Its not the converting to object oriented style what is needed for that code there.

Here are issues i see there:

- pollution of global scope
- mixing fixed CSS rules with Javascript
- use of `.length` attribute within a loop
- no event delegation
- misplacement of `<script>` tag, resulting in use of `window.onload`
- creating new jQuery object when it is not needed
- use of CSS3 selectors in jQuery calls
- no clue how to use `setTimeout()`
- tight coupling to HTML ( id on each slide )

Comment: I am sure you are right about all the wrongs in my code, but it doesn't really help me correct them

Comment: @user1058134 , i have no intention to spoon-feed you the "correct code". They are only direction in which to look, to improve your code quality. I already said that "writing OO" just because it is OO is somewhat pointless.

Comment: I don't want you to spoon feed me, but all you did was mention how bad my code is. What I am looking for is constructive criticism, I am looking for the how and where, how can I write better code, how can I learn about OO, where do i find these resources, what pattern I should follow as a general guideline, stuff like that

Comment: did you try asking google "javascript global scope", "javascript event delegation" or "javascript loop array length" and reading few first link ?

Comment: no i don't even know what those means how could i know to look for them. you are a horrible teacher

Comment: @Chris , that would mean that i am a bad teacher for giving a homework

Comment: I would also add "bad code formatting" to the list (the class :). The "class" here actually has quite a bit of useful information densely packed :), and one could learn a lot by simply asking google (or bing). However, some of them may indeed need to be reworded before cut'n'paste, e.g. misplacement of <script> as "best place to put the script tag"